# Entity Data Model Wizard closes for VS 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I am using VS 2010 , when I want to create entity model, the entity model wizard closes with no error, when I choose from Database...I could not understand the reason and also no idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: are you importing new tables or sync-ing changes to existing ones?

Comment: this is the 1st time im using entity framework, i created a new mvc application, clicked on models , add new item, selected data and then ADO.NET Entity Data Model and then added it, selected 'Generate from database' then the wizard closes

Comment: bloody bloody. Im at a loss. best I can think is checking connect string in web config for EF. Even that feels like a reach cause issues would end with an exception... maybe delete and re-add the data model... also a reach but WTF

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed any third party add-ins in VS2010?   Please try to launch VS2010 in Safe Mode and test the behavior again to avoid any third party add-ins’ effect.   For detail, please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx.

Besides, are there any problems when you create a new Entity Data Model?   Here is a tutorial about how to create an Entity Data Model, http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/creating-an-ado-net-entity-framework-entity-data-model/.

hope this works .